# Lightbox For Youtube Videos

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, youtube, modal-dialog, lightbox

I'm using lightbox to play a video when an image is clicked. I can't find the tutorial I followed but as of right now it works perfectly.

Here is an example of the code I'm using:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5ln4uR4TwQ?rel=0" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="youtubevideos">
  <img src="/img/placeholder.png" alt="pet-owners" width="1600" height="420" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-23442" />
</a>
```

The problem I'm having is when the video is over the recommended videos displays. I've been reading that all I have to do is add a ?rel=0 to the end of the youtube link and that should fix it. However I realized since my method doesn't embed the video this won't work. Any ideas what I should do next?

Sorry I didn't set up a JsFiddle wasn't too sure how to load the lightbox css and js.

I'm also using boostrap 3 . Thank you.